# 2 jQuery toggleClass's showing div's - one link closing the other

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, slidetoggle

I have 2 div's that I toggle and show using the jQuery toggleClass's below:

**Script 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ($) {
        var search_wrapper = $('.search-options');
           $('a.sort').click(function () {
              $(this).toggleClass('show');
              search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
              $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-search fa-times");
              return false;
          });
        });
</script>
```

**Script 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ($) {
        var search_wrapper = $('.search-filters');
            $('a.filter').click(function () {
              $(this).toggleClass('show');
              search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
              $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-search fa-times");
              return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

**My issue**

When one link is clicked and then the other, both div's are both open.

What I would like is when one is clicked & then the other, the 1st one is closed and vise-versa.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, use `$('a.filter').toggleClass('show')` inside `a.sort` click function

and use `$('a.sort').toggleClass('show')` inside `a.filter` function.

---

Here's the combined script:

```
$(function ($) {
    var search_wrapper = $('.search-options');
    $('a.sort').click(function () {
        $('a.filter').toggleClass('show')
        $(this).toggleClass('show');
        search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
        $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-search fa-times");
        return false;
    });
    var search_wrapper = $('.search-filters');
    $('a.filter').click(function () {
        $('a.sort').toggleClass('show')
        $(this).toggleClass('show');
        search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
        $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-search fa-times");
        return false;
     });
});
```